# Finding a character inside a string in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to remove all the characters from a string expect whatever character is between a certain set of characters. So for example I have the input of Grade:2/2014-2015 and I want the output of just the grade, 2.

I'm thinking that I need to use the FIND function to grab whatever is between the : and the / , this also needs to work with double characters such 10 however I believe that it would work so long as the defining values with the FIND function are correct.

Unfortunately I am totally lost on this when using the FIND function however if there is another function that would work better I could probably figure it out myself if I knew what function.

Comment: Does every record start with "Grade:"?

Comment: Yes, every record will follow the same format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not particularly elegant but `=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,FIND("/",A1) - FIND(":",A1) - 1)` would work.

`MID` takes start and length,`FIND` returns the index of a given character.

Edit:
As pointed out, "Grade:" is fixed length so the following would work just as well:
`=MID(A1,7,FIND("/",A1) - 7)`

Comment: +1 most dynamic answer although could immediately substitute the Grade: which is static

Answer (score 1):

You could use LEFT() to remove "Grade:"

And then use and then use LEFTB() to remove the year.

Look at [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/left-leftb-functions-HP010062568.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010102341) link here. This is the way I would go about it.

Answer (score 0):

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C4, "Grade:", ""), "/2014-2015", "")

where C4 is the name of your cell.

Comment: I think you forgot to attach the screenshot however I do need this to be formula because the data will change and I want it to output the grade automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much! I also learned a new function today haha

Comment: No problem, mark the answer as right so the question doesn't appear in the unanswered questions anymore.

Comment: this will not work when the year changes to 2015-2016 and / or you are using past year ranges.

Comment: citation: Yes, every record will follow the same format

Comment: format is different to content. If the content changes then your substitution will not recognise the change. For example 2015-2016. Format refers to a change such as 15-16